# read files in server folder (folder is created with the name of session keys)

Tags: php, session, readfile

i have written a php script to create a folder in my server name with the session key and i store some files there.But when i try to read files in the folder which is named in session key, it is not possible. Is there any reason to forbidden reading files inside that folder.

Comment: PHP session files are usually created by the server user "Apache". Your FTP user may not have read access to those files or the session directory. Check the permissons on the directory/files.

Comment: folder permission is 0700